¿Es posible cambiar el mensaje de error de conectividad o redireccionar a un panel informativo en una aplicación móvil desarrollada con GeneXus 18U9?
Estoy trabajando con genexus18u9 para moviles y necesito que cuando la aplicacion no tenga conexion con el servidor mostrar panel informativo o cambiar el mensaje predeterminado que tiene genexus, la aplicacion trabaja Connectivity Support online.
Trate de crear un panel offonline pero cuando de este panel llamaba a un panel online sale error en genexus.
